# Hard drive swap

Tags: laptop-repair

I broke my company laptop (I'm clumsy) and I have had the hard drive checked and it still works.  My boss is kindly buying a similar laptop for me.  My question is what would happen if I took out the hard drive from the new laptop and replaced it with my old one?  Could I just continue working with my data without changes or is there some id that gets stored somewhere that must match with the hardware being used?  The laptops are both from HP and the OS was Windows 8.

Comment: If you simply took HDD A out of Laptop A and placed it in Laptop B Windows 8 would not boot. While its possible to migrate an installation of Windows, it requires getting rid of the existing drivers, and loading the correct drivers. The process of loading the corect drivers is normally done when Windows 8 is installed. You would be better of to simply migrate your personal files.  **Even though its possible to move a Windows installation the migration of an OEM license in a case like this is not even with the same OEM**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if both laptops have the exact same hardware, the OS should boot successfully. It may decide to "find new hardware", or download some drivers, but basically will just treat the whole event as if you just changed hardware after shutting down.

Several registry values contain specific machine and hardware IDs (like network interfaces MAC address, Bluetooth IDs etc.) but they should update well.

Your only challenge would be if there's a different BIOS that does not recognize the drive as a boot drive - but that can be overcome as well.

So I'd give it a try.